# Numpy Arrays : Although A = B[:] creates an numpy array object A with id(A) != id(B) . It still gets updated , unlike lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to do a shallow copy of numpy arrays using [:], like i normally would do with lists. However i found that this does not behave same as lists. I know that i can use .copy() method to solve this. But just wanted to understand whats happening under the hood with numpy here. can anyone please elaborate.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = a[:]
print(id(b) == id(a))  # Ids are different, So different objects right ?
b[3] = 10
print(a, b) # Both a and b got updated
```

Comment: i think it's a different pointer, but it points to the same place in memory. sort of like int* a, b; int c; a = &c; b = a

Comment: The operator [:] for numpy arrays creates a view (that is why the objects are different), but do not copies the internal data, if you need a copy do .copy

Comment: agree with @DaniMesejo. you can verify this by using b.base which gives you a. read this for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) (emphasis mine):

> Note that slices of arrays do not copy the internal array data but
> only produce new views of the original data. **This is different from
> list or tuple slicing** and an explicit copy() is recommended if the
> original data is not required anymore.

So just do:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = a.copy()
b[3] = 10
print(a, b)
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 3 4 5] [ 1  2  3 10  5]
```

Notice that the reason the ids are different is because `b` is a view of `a` and indeed a different object.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `[:]` in numpy does not copy the data, but the reference. So that kind of behavior is expected. It's same as you do the `a = b` directly. Use the `np.copy(array)` to copy the values.

If there's array `a = [1, 2]`, and the empty variable `b`, so the behavior of assignments of numpy array are summarized into this:

1. These kind of assignments will copy the reference, so if you change the `b` later, it will also change `a`.

```
b = a
b[1] = 10
print(b == a) # True
```

```
b = a[:]
b[1] = 10
print(b == a) # True
```

2. This kind of assignment will copy the **values**, so if you change `b` later, `a` won't change.

```
b = np.copy(a)
b[1] = 10
print(b == a) # True
```

...and if the `dtype=object`, the use of `deepcopy()` from package `copy` will make sure all the values copied.

```
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b[1] = 10
print(b == a) # True
```